# Clear Browser by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

The code works well but I m f acing the problem in the function `stopCounting()` which also removes the child node of `<div id ='space'>`.

Whenever I click the `Stop` it clears the browser but after to click the Start button putting some value, it skips the value of `counter.currValue == 35`; `counter.currValue == 40`; `counter.currValue == 50` and also doesn't load the image.

I want to clear the browser after uploading the image. It works for 1st time, from 2nd times onward, it skips the values 35, 40, 50 and the images as well.

Any explanation or solution from why it skips those value from 2nd times?

```
var buttonStartField = document.getElementById('btn2');
var buttonEndField = document.getElementById('btn1');
var startValueField = document.getElementById('startValue');

buttonStartField.addEventListener('click', startCounting);
buttonEndField.addEventListener('click', stopCounting);

var counter = {
     currValue : 0,
     interval : null
};

 function increment() {

  counter.currValue++;

if (counter.currValue == 35) {
    showImage();
    document.getElementById('counter1').innerHTML = 'Value:'
            + counter.currValue + '</br>';
} else if (counter.currValue == 40) {
    showImage1();
    document.getElementById('counter2').innerHTML = 'Value:'
            + counter.currValue + '</br>';
}
if (counter.currValue == 50) {
    showImage2();
    document.getElementById('counter3').innerHTML = 'Value:'
            + counter.currValue + '</br>';
}

document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Value:' + counter.currValue
        + '</br>';
  }

function startCounting() {  
  counter.currValue = startValueField.value || 0;
  counter.interval = setInterval(increment, 1000);
 }
    function stopCounting() {
      clearInterval(counter.interval);
      clearContent();
}

 function clearContent(node) {
    var div = document.getElementById('space');
     while (div.hasChildNodes()) {
      div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
     }
  }
```

HTML

```
<body>
       <!-- @content --> 
        <div id= "div1">             
                <p id="counter"> </p> 
        </div>  
        <form class="f1">                   

            <input id= "startValue" type="number">
            <input class="button" id = "btn2" type="button" value="Start">
            <input class="button" id = "btn1" type="button" value="Stop">           

        </form>

            <div id="space">
                  <div id="laser"><p id="counter1"></p> </div>                    
                  <div id="laser1"><p id="counter2"></div>
                  <div id="laser2"><p id="counter3"></div>                                      
            </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: What are the functions `showImage()` (1 and 2)

Comment: A jsFiddle demo would probably make this trivial for SO to solve for you :)

Comment: Have you tried to print the currValue to see if it is 35, 40 or 50 in any moment during the execution of the code? Try using `console.log("Current Value: " + currValue);`

Comment: post your html code please

Comment: @Mark  here is the demo http://jsbin.com/uxAgOLOq/2/edit

Comment: @altius Your link errors out for me...

Comment: @altius I have 4 warnings on the link you provided and the Start button doesn't appear to do anything.  I"m not sure if your first language is english but please try and be clear, that last comment made my head hurt.

Comment: @Mark 4 warnings, all for `</br>`. `Start` button appears and works  also.

Comment: @Mark Now everything is ok. U can see - no warning and working Start button

Answer (score 1):

I think you have asked two questions:

1) `<div id ='space'>` is being emptied when you click 'stop'.

Solution = Remove the `clearContent();` from `stopCounting()` function. Or Edit the `clearContent()` function as all it does is remove all children.

And the main question

2) It appears that you are skipping '35', '40' and '50' when it is counting.

The problem is that you are calling jQuery (animation) functions but you do not load jQuery to take care of them. When it hits this error, it ends the function and does not display the counter. Then the next iteration of the setInterval kicks in and it works again.

Solution: remove the jQuery, or load jQuery in the head of the document

```
    // this is all jQuery
$('#laser').animate({
    width : 300,
    height : 300
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Comment: Well If you simply remove the function clearContent(), It works fine. At the value 35, 40 and 50 all corresponding images are appearing. You can stop the counting and start again and also start from a new value. 
Now my question is to stop the counting and clear the browser together. How can I do that? If the counting crosses 35, the green image appears. Now some one wants to start again from 30 or less than 35, if the browser is not clear, updating the image doesn't reflect.

Comment: It appears your jsbin is missing a lot of code then... To answer your question; Instead of **removing** the image, why dont you **hide** it?